# Will didFinishLaunchingWithOptions run after new version installation?

Tags: iphone, background

An iOS 4 user is using my app and have it running in background, a new version is available and the user download that new version from App Store.

Will my app quit and restart when the new version has downloaded and installed so that I can make sure that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will run the first time after the new version is installed? I have some important update-stuff that need to run to update the database and want to make sure this code runs after they have downloaded the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app will not quit, if already running. However, the next time the app is launched didFinishLaunching WithOptions will indeed run.

Comment: So if the user have the app in background, updates and open the app he will be able to run the new version without didFinishLaunchingWithOptions runned first? I that case maybe I should put my update stuff in applicationWillEnterForeground?

Comment: From what I've observed: If you launch a app, then send app to the background, then download the updated app; what happens is: The app remains in the system tray, the updating progress bar appears on both the system tray and springboard. When you move the app from the background to the foreground. The old app appears to be running.

Comment: Ok, so the user need to close the app to run the new version then? This is really interesting because a lot of users of iOS 4 doesn't have a clue that an app is running in the background when they press the home button.